# How to restart Tomcat 7 and use management console on Openshift?

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I'm using standard "Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)" cartridge.
I would like to use tomcat management console, but I don't know how. I also would like to know how to restart tomcat via ssh.
Please, help me :)

Comment: Do you have ssh access for the openshift account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restart tomcat you can use the 'rhc app restart' command.

The tomcat version on OpenShift does not come with the administration console.  To learn more about using tomcat on OpenShift Online, you should check out the Servers section of the Developer Portal (https://developers.openshift.com)